# SQL SERVER Updating a columnA in table1 with table2's columnA only if (CountRows(table1.ColumnB = table2.ColumnB) == 1)

Tags: sql-server, count

Say there are two tables, table 1 and table 2.
Each table has two columns, ColumnA and ColumnB.
I want to update table1.ColumnA with table2.ColumnB when
table1.ColumnB and table2.ColumnB are the same.
However, there maybe more than one row in table2 where table1.ColumnB and table2.ColumnB are the same. If this is the case, I don't want to update the column. I want to update the column only where there's only 1 case where table1.ColumnB and table2.ColumnB are the same

The code is for SQL SERVER. i tried the following but has syntax errors that I can't fathom.

```
SET [ColumnA] = 

(

IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE ColumnB = Table1.ColumnB) = 1)

BEGIN

SELECT [ColumnA]

FROM Table2

WHERE Table1.ColumnB = ColumnB

END

)

WHERE [ColumnA] IS NULL;
```

Comment: Please explain your problem briefly. It's quite unclear what you are asking

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostGreSQL, etc, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE
  Table1
SET
  ColumnA = Table2.ColumnA
FROM
(
  SELECT MAX(ColumnA) AS ColumnA, ColumnB 
    FROM Table2
GROUP BY ColumnB
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
  AS Table2
WHERE
      Table1.ColumnB  = Table2.ColumnB
  AND Table1.ColumnA IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just set 2 different variables 
(SET ColumnA= select count(*) blabla..as you did; and then do the same for ColumnB)
Then you can just compare these 2 values (IF ColumnA==ColumnB)